# How to go about IOS Push Notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im currently developing an app in Swift. I'm at the last stage of the app where I just need to integrate push notifications to the lock screen when certain user actions occur.

I'm going for something like how **Instagram sends a push notification when a new user follows you or likes your post.**

My entire backend is using firebase, and i've looked into firebase cloud messaging and I dont know if it has the capability to perform notifications like this.

I've watched tutorials and read documentation and I know you can push notifications to users from the console but I'm looking for notifications to be published and pushed based off specific user actions.

I know this is a very broad questions so what I want to know is:

**A) Are notifications like instagram possible through Firebase cloud messeging?**

**B) If not, can you point me in the direction of how to figure this out?**

Thank you!

Comment: A) Yes, they can be. Here's how to do it [Firebase In App Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging) and/or [Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)

Comment: @jay And this if for pushing notifications to the lock screen? Thanks for the info btw!

Comment: It will display on the Lock Screen if your app asks for and receives notification permission from the user. You may want to look at [cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) to send the notification.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks Paul! Do you have experience in setting this up, i wrote my application entirely using swiftUI, and i'm not sure if I can integrate this into my project?

Comment: Which part? Requesting notification permissions or the triggers? Firestone triggers are server side node.is.

Comment: I understand requesting permissions for notifications which can be done using swift.  For the firestore triggers it requires node.js, so in your opinion do you think that it would be something I could pick up on relatively easily or should I try and partner with someone who already knows node.js? @Paulw11

Comment: It's pretty much just JavaScript, so give it a go.

Comment: Notifications on the lock screen are fairly straightforward and there a number or other question about that. Try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498934/firebase-messaging-not-waking-up-ios-device-when-receiving-push-notifs) with some pretty complete code.

Answer (score 0):

A) Are notifications like instagram possible through Firebase cloud messaging?

- Yes

Firebase send the push to APNS first then APNS send push notification to iOS devices.

If user 'A' do any action  then that specific action will be transferred/send to staging/production server via apis. Based on your business logic staging/production server will send push notification to users(FCM token).

I hope this is helpful or you can explain the exact issue your are facing.

Comment: Can this be done in swift? Or is some code need to be written in Java. The part that  is confusing me is setting up the server code. From a high level I understand your answer and it was helpful but is there any place where I can find documentation for this? What should I type in to dig more into this? @Deepak Singh