# FirebaseMessaging: App not showing notification when screen is locked or some other app is open iOS Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have developed an app on flutter which contains calling functionality. It uses firebasemessaging for notifications. So, when App is terminated from app switcher, the notifications work fine or when the app is in foreground. But, when screen is locked or some other app is open, It doesn't show any notification.
Here is my code. I have added this same function to FirebaseMessaging.onMessage and onBackgroundMessage.

```
Future _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage msg) async {
  print("--------------------------------------------------------");

  print("Handling a background message: ${msg.messageId}");
  if (msg.data["clearNotification"] != null) {
    clearNotification();
    return;
  }

  const androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'hubb channel id', // channel ID
    'Hubb Channel', // channel name
    channelDescription: 'hubb! everyone is here',
    fullScreenIntent: true,
    sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('ringing_sound'),
    playSound: true,
    importance: Importance.max,
    priority: Priority.high,
    visibility: NotificationVisibility.public,
    ticker: 'ticker',
    // autoCancel:false,
  );
  const iosnotificationDetails = IOSNotificationDetails(
    sound: "ringing_sound.wav",
    presentAlert: true,
    presentSound: true,
  );

  const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    iOS: iosnotificationDetails,
  );
  var flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      await initializeFlutterLocalNotification();
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    1,
    'Incoming Call',
    'Hubb incoming call',
    platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: jsonEncode(msg.data),
  );
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307743/flutter-show-notification-on-lock-screen, follow this

Comment: @Vikas actually my problem is with iOS these answers are for android.

Comment: Do you get notifications on iOS when app is in foreground?

Comment: yes, even I get them when the app is terminated but screen is not locked and some other app is not open.

Comment: I have given you the answer Hamza, upvote it if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

This is a setting of iOS user to be changed and not the developer, so you can do this and it should work fine:

You can allow access to Notification Center on the Lock Screen.

1. Go to Settings  > Face ID & Passcode (on an iPhone with Face ID) or Touch ID & Passcode (on other iPhone models).
2. Enter your passcode.
3. Scroll down and turn on Notification Center (below Allow Access When Locked).

Reference:

[https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph6534c01bc/ios#:~:text=Show%20recent%20notifications%20on%20the%20Lock%20Screen&text=Go%20to%20Settings%20%3E%20Face%20ID,below%20Allow%20Access%20When%20Locked](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph6534c01bc/ios#:%7E:text=Show%20recent%20notifications%20on%20the%20Lock%20Screen&text=Go%20to%20Settings%20%3E%20Face%20ID,below%20Allow%20Access%20When%20Locked)).

Comment: Thank You very much. But, I don't think this will help much as  Notification Center is already turned on and I am getting other app notifications on lock screen as well. It's only that I am getting this issue on the app I am working on currently.

Comment: Are you facing this issue on one OS version or all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498934/firebase-messaging-not-waking-up-ios-device-when-receiving-push-notifs